# Appropriate settings to register broker/port information for Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, broker

I read the following from [confluence wiki for kafka](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-WhydoIseeerror%22Shouldnotsetlogendoffsetonpartition%22inthebrokerlog?) and I am quoting it below:

> **Why do I see error "Should not set log end offset on partition" in the**
>   **broker log?**
>
> Typically, you will see errors like the following.
>
> kafka.common.KafkaException: Should not set log end offset on
>   partition [test,22]'s local replica 4 ERROR
>   [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-6], Error for partition [test,22] to broker
>   6:class
>   kafka.common.UnknownException(kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
>
> > A common problem is that more than one broker registered the same
> >     host/port in Zookeeper. As a result, the replica fetcher is confused
> >     when fetching data from the leader. To verify that, you can use a
> >     Zookeeper client shell to list the registration info of each broker.
> >     The Zookeeper path and the format of the broker registration is
> >     described in Kafka data structures in Zookeeper. You want to make sure
> >     that all the registered brokers have unique host/port.

According to the official documentation, if I do `PLAINTEXT://:9092` then all interfaces will register using `9092` port. `0.0.0.0` means default interface will register using 9092 port.

If this is true, then I don't see how `0.0.0.0:9092` broker registration can never confuse zookeeper? I think if I don't explicitly specify the hostname or ipaddr with portname, Zookeeper will always get confuse since all brokers will register with same interface and port number. I have confirmed that using Zookeeper-shell.bat and running command `get /broker/ids/{id}` command.

The following is from Zookeeper Client Shell enquiry on `/brokers/ids`

```
get /brokers/ids/1
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"0.0.0.0","timestamp":"1500646657734","port":9092,"version":4}
cZxid = 0xe0000000f
ctime = Fri Jul 21 14:17:37 UTC 2017
mZxid = 0xe0000000f
mtime = Fri Jul 21 14:17:37 UTC 2017
pZxid = 0xe0000000f
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x15d6582c70b0001
dataLength = 184
numChildren = 0
get /brokers/ids/2
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"0.0.0.0","timestamp":"1500646657006","port":9092,"version":4}
cZxid = 0xe0000000b
ctime = Fri Jul 21 14:17:37 UTC 2017
mZxid = 0xe0000000b
mtime = Fri Jul 21 14:17:37 UTC 2017
pZxid = 0xe0000000b
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x15d6582c70b0000
dataLength = 184
numChildren = 0
get /brokers/ids/3
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"0.0.0.0","timestamp":"1500646656895","port":9092,"version":4}
cZxid = 0xe00000008
ctime = Fri Jul 21 14:17:36 UTC 2017
mZxid = 0xe00000008
mtime = Fri Jul 21 14:17:36 UTC 2017
pZxid = 0xe00000008
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x35d6582c7800000
dataLength = 184
numChildren = 0
```

Has anyone got a better idea?

Comment: 0.0.0.0:9092 should resolve to the default interface IP address first before registering in zookeeper so you should see 192.168.72.3 or whatever the IP of host default interface is. Please check and confirm.

Comment: @HansJespersen         updated question with my zk output. Also, I guess it won't make much of a difference (dare I say!) but the OS is windows? Shall I cry?

Comment: At least zookeeper sees three unique broker IDs which is the most important thing. Just don't start another broker with ID of 1, 2, or 3 or you will have a problem. You should configure advertised listener parameter in server.properties to be a proper IP address of each broker so that any clients can reach the brokers.

Comment: @HansJespersen      Alternatively, using `PLAINTEXT://hostname:port` should also work, correct? Should we recommend any additional note in the documentation for this at all?

Comment: Host name is not always unique so fully qualified domain name is even better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kafka server.properties , there are two property keys:

**listeners**

> The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
>   java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
>   FORMAT:
>        listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
>   EXAMPLE:
>        listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

**advertised.listeners**

> Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and
>   consumers. If not set,  it uses the value for "listeners" if
>   configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value  returned from
>   java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().

OK. Pay attention to the details for advertised.listeners. if you don't configure this property, it will use the listeners default. when you set listeners to 0.0.0.0:9092, It will listen all net interface of your Kafka server. But if the advertised.listeners also set to 0.0.0.0, then others will not know how to connect to your Kafka server, Consumer, Producer and Zookeeper. all of these will fail to find where is your Kafka server.

So in a word, The advertised.listeners should be set your public net ip which other machine in Internet can connnect to your server with this ip.

Comment: `@qfhyj`         Okay I get the point. But IP addresses aren't always static and might change due to NAT address reassignment. So, will it always work with IP address. As Hans's comment suggest above, isn't fully qualified domain name better?

Comment: Both can work if the ping command works.  As for which is better I think It depends on your machines number.

Comment: `@qfhyj` yes I agree. I am keen to use FQDN like `mymachinewNo.myavailabilitydomain.com`. But I do understand this now and thanks for explaining the interface binding issue above.